# Looking for a descriptive word(s)) to describe digest/summation/pocket culture

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, popular-refrains, neologisms

I am looking for a generic word(s) to describe summary digest cultural of modern society. (or a Neologism)

A word(s) for culture that describes "Take what is useful, discard what is useless"

e.g.

- the current culture of digested advice in self-help books rather than studying the fundamentals
- follow the "10 steps to success" in a blog post
- a smartphone app to do X,
- a 3 month course to get you a job instead of a 4 year degree,
- advertisements that promote earning a high monthly income in a short time.
- Taking the best characteristics of other successful people's lives
- Watching short a bunch of youtube videos rather than a hour long documentary
- Reading your facebook/twitter feed instead of reading a book

Basically I want to say taking what is useful from prior knowledge and summarising it to your benefit.

**Sentence examples:**

Bruce Lee has a saying "Absorb what is useful, discard what is useless". This throwing away irrelevant information to your specific situation is called a ____ cultural approach

The world has developed a competitive culture, not based on fair quantification, but rather necessitates pragmatism to become successful. John knows he is not the best candidate for the job, so he decides to flatter the hiring committee with compliments and feed their egos. This _____ (cultural) behavior makes him one of the leading candidates despite his lack of experience and qualification.

After reading self help books, training videos and articles on how to make a $5K per month, John realized that this _____ *summarised/digest/pocket* advice didn't help him.

Tom is a call center agent. He could follow an approach of calling a telephone number on his lead list and talking and listening in calls unique to each situation are then selling the product, or alternatively following a script and phoning as many numbers. He finds he is more successful with the latter approach
This quantity over quality culture in call centers is called ____ approach/culture.

David follows a pragmatic approach to learning. He decides he will attend networking events and get a job within a year, then learn on the job rather than waste 4 years learning knowledge at university that gets outdated once his graduates. He is following a ___ strategy.

Steve downloaded a dating app that promises to match him with his ideal mate based on a questionnaire he completed. Steve hopes this _____ cultural approach will result in him having to go on less dates until him meets his long-term partner.

Peter skipped studying and lied on his resume that he had a degree to get a programming job.
Sally used her friendship with Jane to get a promotion ahead of better qualified candidates. This approach of taking shortcuts to get a good salary is becoming more and more common in this ____ culture.

People don't have time today to read every page in books. They prefer to read summaries written by others. This never used to be the case but in information-overload society necessitates this ____ phenomenon

**Words I have thought of that I don't think fit:**

*pocket*. I have googled pocket advice and pocket self-help but can get no reference to these terms apart from the website pocket and a physical pocket. I don't think it is commonly used but somehow, I thought of these little books that fit in your pocket meaning summary

*shortcut*. A shortcut means a quick way to a solution as if the path is the same as doing the long proper long way.
I need a word that explains more that the end result is also impacted. The end result in title is the same, but the end result of other aspects are not. E.g. You can't fake a medical doctor's degree and start practicing. This is not just a shortcut to a goal but has negative repercussions.

*duct-tape/hack-job*.- The definition is completion of a task in the quickest possible time at the expense of quality or attention to detail. The word has a negative connotation as it implies a negative consequence. I am looking for a word that is more neutral and not as offensive. Like you can use it in business terms. Sometimes it can be a hack job that gives problems later. Othertimes it won't matter. Point is, it has to describe the culture that isn't neccessary negative.

*digest, summation* culture. If I say the words it doesn't sound right

*get rich, hustle, fake it until make it*. These are not words that explain the summarized nature of this culture. I want a word to apply to different situations, not just applicable just to getting wealthy.

*end-in-mind* culture. It's almost like goal setting where you have an end in mind of achieving a goal without any moral or ethical concern how it impacts others.

*dog-eat-dog* culture is doing whatever where as I am trying to limit it to a specific cultural aspect of summation for one's own benefit rather than anything goes.
*pragmatism, stoic* is more of a philosophy. I am trying to explain a current zeitgeist culture of summation.

You have to consciously work hard to achieve something, you just don't follow the same script because you compete against others. Soon everyone else follows an unconventional approach because following the conventional they get nowhere. You do it not because you like a shortened approach but because you have to or you won't read the book or get a job or make money. It's not a quick fix. it's a cultural phenomenon.

Of all the words I think Pocket culture, Summation culture or Digest culture fits the best. It just sounds strange when I write it.

Comment: Somewhere between short-cut and streamline. But tldr;

Comment: Yes, but what is the word between shortcut and streamline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some words that you could use:

- **[Abridged](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abridged):** made shorter by having some details or less important information removed:
- **[Minimalist](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/minimalist):** belonging or relating to a style in art, design, and theatre that uses the smallest range of materials and colours possible, and only very simple shapes or forms.

Or the following words:

- **[Shorthand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorthand)**
- **[CliffsNotes](https://grammarist.com/usage/cliffs-notes/)**
- **[Utilitarian](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/utilitarian)**

Answer (score 1):

> It's not a quick fix. it's a cultural phenomenon.

I would like to challenge the above statement. Those words *are* used together in the media and general conversation.

"instant fix" or "quick fix"

> *Meghan Markle warned against the growing “instant fix” culture* https://www.express.co.uk/news/royal/1198883/Meghan-Markle-news-Duchess-of-Sussex-Prince-Harry-Royal-Family-latest

> *The Perils of the Quick Fix Culture* https://teachtalks.co.uk/the-perils-of-the-quick-fix-culture/

---

P.S. Thanks for the thorough elucidation of your question.

Comment: Insta fix culture has a negative connotation. I need to explain something in more neutral terms that explains "Take what is useful but discard what is not"

Comment: @greay - Okay. I'll think again. P.S. do you want an existing term or are you asking us to invent a new and pithy phrase?

Comment: I am not sure if it exists. So both. Can I use the word pocket- culture or is there a better word(s) or phrase?

Comment: I think the problem for me is that the examples don't seem to imply a constant meaning. Bruce Lee's example is what I would call an *aphorism*, Lying to get a job is simply a *deception*.

Answer (score -1):

A word as simple as **selective**. A selective approach.

> *selective* ...
>
> 2. [adjective]
>
> *When someone is selective, they choose things carefully, for example, the things that they buy or do.*

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/selective)]

Obviously, there is an idiomatic broadening to include the process as well as the person/s involved.

*selective breeding* / *a selective approach*

The synonym *discriminating*, which AHD gives in a definition, is usually applied only to the person/s doing the judicious choosing.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a *refining approach*

refine ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refine))

> 1: to free (something, such as metal, sugar, or oil) from impurities or unwanted material

> 2: to free from moral imperfection : ELEVATE

> 3: to improve or perfect by pruning or polishing
> refine a poetic style

> 4: to reduce in vigor or intensity

> 5: to free from what is coarse, vulgar, or uncouth